# Cocoa NSPoint to Quartz NSPoint - Flip Y cordinate

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

In macOS programming, We know that

- Quartz uses a coordinate space where the origin (0, 0) is at the top-left of the primary display. Increasing y goes down.
- Cocoa uses a coordinate space where the origin (0, 0) is the bottom-left of the primary display and increasing y goes up.

Now am using a Quartz API - CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to crop an image , which takes a rectangle as a param. The rect has the Y origin coming from Cocoa's mousedown events.

Thus i get crops at inverted locations...

I tried this code to flip my Y co-ordinate in my cropRect

```
 //Get the point in MouseDragged event
 NSPoint currentPoint = [self.view convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
 CGRect nsRect = CGRectMake(currentPoint.x , currentPoint.y,   
                                  circleSizeW,  circleSizeH);
 //Now Flip the Y please!
 CGFloat flippedY = self.imageView.frame.size.height - NSMaxY(nsRectFlippedY);
 CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, flippedY, circleSizeW, circleSizeH);
```

But for the areas on the top, i wrong FlippedY coordinates.
If i click near top edge of the view, i get flippedY = 510 to 515
At the top edge it should be between 0 to 10   :-|

Can someone point me to the correct and reliable way to Flip
the Y coordinate in such circumstances? Thank you!

Here is sample project in GitHub highlighting the issue
https://github.com/kamleshgk/SampleMacOSApp

[image: ISSUE Screenshot]

Comment: When you say "The rect has the Y origin coming from Cocoa's mousedown events", do you mean `-locationInWindow`? That is, as its name suggests, in window-relative coordinates, not screen coordinates.

Comment: What is `nsRect`?

Comment: @KenThomases 
Yes the Y from point comes from this code - 
NSPoint currentPoint = [self.view convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

Comment: @Willeke nsRect is Rect that contains Y point from this code

NSPoint currentPoint = [self.view convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

Comment: @Willeke see updated code in Question for nsRect! thanks!

Comment: Please show code, not pictures of code.

Comment: @matt Code is shown earlier in the question.  Thank you.

Comment: But not enough of it for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @matt I added sample project on Github , if u want to reproduce
https://github.com/kamleshgk/SampleMacOSApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Charles mentioned, the Core Graphics API you are using requires coordinates relative to the image (not the screen). The important thing is to convert the event location from window coordinates to the view which most closely corresponds to the image's location and then flip it relative to that same view's bounds (not frame). So:

```
NSView *relevantView = /* only you know which view */;
NSPoint currentPoint = [relevantView convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
// currentPoint is in Cocoa's y-up coordinate system, relative to relevantView, which hopefully corresponds to your image's location

currentPoint.y = NSMaxY(relevantView.bounds) - currentPoint.y;
// currentPoint is now flipped to be in Quartz's y-down coordinate system, still relative to relevantView/your image
```

Answer (score 0):

The rect you pass to `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` should be in coordinates relative to the input image's size, not screen coordinates. Assuming the size of the input image matches the size of the view to which you've converted your point, you should be able to achieve this by subtracting the rect's corner from the image's height, rather than the screen height.

Comment: Agreed. The ImageView in on the View and is of the same size.  
When i click at top of the ImageView, the Y coordinate of the clicked point is between 0 and 10.   I get cropped image of the bottom rather than the top - where i clicked.
 So you suggest this?
CGFloat flippedY = NSMaxY(imageview.height) - NSMaxY(nsRect);

Comment: @kamyFC It would just be `imageview.height`, no `NSMaxY()` around that part.

Comment: @KenThomases
CGFloat flippedY = self.imageView.image.size.height - NSMaxY(nsRectFlippedY); .........With this code - I get Y value as 725 - if i MouseClick at the top of image  ..........  CGFloat flippedY = self.imageView.frame.size.height - NSMaxY(nsRectFlippedY); ..... With this code , i get Y value as -72 -  if i MouseClick at the top of image 
.......The second solution is close.  But not quiet...

Comment: @KenThomases I added a screenshot in the question after using the formulae suggested.

Comment: Is the `imageView` the content view of the window? Or is it a subview (or further descendant) of the content view? Might it be positioned so it's partially cut off at the top? In your code snippet, you convert the point to the coordinate space of `self.view`, but you're flipping it relative to `self.imageView`. You should use the same view for both. Which you choose depends on what you want the final rect to be relative to.

Comment: @KenThomases Excellent Point!   There were no issues with the constraints, The Content View was ImageView which was subview of Window's View.

I changed the code to 
CGFloat flippedY = self.window.contentView.frame.size.height - NSMaxY(nsRectFlippedY);

And it works now.
Can you answer it and i will marked as Solved, so you get the credit!  Thanks again friend!